# How to replace a block of text with a "query-like" approach all at once?

Tags: search, replace, query-replace-regexp

I want to search and replace a block of text with a "query-like" approach all at once.

For example, if I have

```
\emph{``Foo $\bar$ baz''}
```

to be replaced by

```
\emph{Foo $\bar$ baz}
```

using a "query-like" approach all at once, how could I do?

I have tried something like this:

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)

  ;; \emph{``Foo''} --> \emph{Foo}
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "\\\\emph{``" nil t)
    (save-excursion
      (let* ((pos1 (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
             (pos2 (copy-marker (progn
                                  (goto-char (- (match-end 0) 3))
                                  (forward-pexp)
                                  (point))))
             (text (buffer-substring-no-properties (+ pos1 8) (- pos2 3))))

        (query-replace-regexp (concat "\\\\emph{``"
                                      text
                                      "''}")
                              (concat "\\\\emph{"
                                      (regexp-quote text)
                                      "}")
                              nil pos1 pos2)))))
```

but it does not work if there are chars to be escaped (`text` could be everything, even chars to be escaped, like `\` in `LaTeX` macro or `[ ]` or `$...$` or other).

It works if there are no chars to be escaped.

I have just found a solution for this example with a "query-like" approach, i.e.

```
(query-replace-regexp "\\\\emph{``"
                      "\\\\emph{" nil pos1 pos2)

(query-replace-regexp "''}"
                      "}" nil (- pos2 3) pos2)
```

but it is not all at once. I would like to have only one call to `query-replace-regexp`.

**Note**

In [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61921/how-can-i-catch-a-block-of-text-to-be-used-in-a-replacement-part-code) I have found a solution to be used for solving this question.

Comment: Running `query-replace-regexp` interactively with arguments `\\emph{``\(.+\)''} → \\emph{\1}` seems to do the job.

Comment: If you're not using regexps, don't call regexp functions?  `query-replace` vs `query-replace-regexp`.  If you need regexps, use `regexp-quote` to escape special characters in the search pattern.  You've actually used it in your code, but you used it on the *replacement* text, which almost certainly isn't what you intended.

Comment: If each 'query' is for a single known region, then you could using `perform-replace` instead of a `query-replace*` function.

Comment: @phils I have gone by trial and error because, unfortunately, I do not always know how to use the tools that elisp makes available. If I do not need that emacs queries me about replacements to be done, I generally use `perform-replace` with `query-flag` set to `nil`, otherwise I use `query-replace-regexp`. In this way it is easier for me to debug my scripts, each of them has thousands of lines of code: when I call a script and something breaks, I simply set  `query-flag` from `nil` to `t` and so it is easier to find where something is wrong.